# How to get constant literal type inferred from an javascript object imported from another file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a javascript constant map defined in another file (I don't own this file) like this:

```
const obj = {
  prop1: 'val1',
  prop2: 'val2',
}
```

I want to use the literal types from this object while defining one of my types. For example, I want to define a function overload based on these values like this

```
function func(key: typeof obj.prop1): string;
function func(key: typeof obj.prop2): number;
```

when i import this object in my ts file, the default types are the wider types:

`obj.prop1` is type `string`
`obj.prop2` is type `string`

while i would want `obj.prop1` to be type `val1` and `obj.prop2` to be `val2`

is there a way to do that?

- I can modify the original file to add a jsdoc annotation so that this obj is expored as const (I don't own the file)
- I can redefine the obj as enum in my typescript file and use that for getting the constant values (values can get out of sync over time)

Comment: Yikes, I don't think there's any good way to do so.

Comment: I have checked and had some examples however the approach is not foolproof so.

Comment: @MilanSachani may be you can post some of these approaches as an answer